# Is there a way to force 'Simplify' to use some assumptions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, assumptions

First time poster. I have a basic question about 'Simplify'.

I am encountering a problem when trying to simplify some algebraic expressions, where I find an unexpected behaviour of the 'Simplify' function. I am using Mathematica 13.3 on Windows.

Consider the following problem: we have a somewhat complicated expression `expr` depending on many variables, and we have a system of equations `eqs` that these variables satisfy. We then want to simplify `expr` using `eqs`, by calling

```
Simplify[expr,eqs]
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to always give the desired result... Here is the simplest example in which I managed to produce a puzzling (to me) behaviour of 'Simplify'. Consider the following expression and equations:

```
expr = 2 + k[1, 1, 1, 0];
eqs1 = k[1, 1, 1, 0] == u[2, 0];
eqs2 = k[1, 1, 1, 0] == x;
Simplify[expr, eqs1]
Simplify[expr, eqs2]
```

where I am considering `k[1,1,1,0]`, `u[2,0]`, and `x` as some coefficients in a more complicated expression. When I run the above code, it returns

```
2+u[2,0]
2+k[1,1,1,0]
```

It's like Mathematica has decided that `u[2,0]` is simpler than `k[1,1,1,0]`, while `x` is more complicated, and I can't understand why. I have tried using some other simple ComplexityFunction, as well as 'FullSimplify', but I keep finding the same behaviour. Hence my question: is there a way to force Simplify to consider `x` to be simpler than the other object `k[1,1,1,0]`?

P.s. I realise that this simple example could be solved by using a rule, rather than asking Simplify to handle the renaming of the variables. However, I am interested in a situation where I have a large set of variables and equations, and using a rule in that case seems to me to be more complicated...

Comment: Not sure why it does not work, nor why this does: `eqs2 = k[1, 1, 1, 0] == Unevaluated@x`.

Comment: I think you should perhaps look into `Eliminate` rather than `Simplify`. It may be a more appropriate tool for the task.

Comment: `expr /. Rule @@ eqs2`

Comment: You defined `expr` and then referenced `exp`. Your code would not execute as written.

Comment: @Ghoster thank you, I corrected the typo.